# bypassing the windows terminal using the windows api library

Tags: c, algorithm, winapi, optimization, data-structures

> Condition: make a visual bypass of the terminal of the windows operating system with the sign "*" using the windows api library.
> The program is written in the C programming language, in the Clion IDE. For the dimensions of the console, take the standard 80*25 (the last line must not be filled). The tour starts from the conventional center of the console and gradually spirals clockwise, ending in the upper left corner.
>
> Here is the workaround:
>
> [image]

text of program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Function to print '*' at a specific position in the console
void Paint(HANDLE hout, int i, int j) {
    COORD pos; // Structure to store coordinates
    pos.X = j; // Set X coordinate
    pos.Y = i; // Set Y coordinate
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hout, pos); // Set cursor position in the console
    printf("*"); // Print '*'
    Sleep(50); // Delay for a better visual effect
}

int main() {
    int centerX, centerY;

    HANDLE hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // Get handle to standard output
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi; // Structure to store information about the console screen buffer
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hout, &csbi); // Get information about the console screen buffer

    centerX = csbi.srWindow.Right / 2; // Find the center of the console horizontally
    centerY = csbi.srWindow.Bottom / 2; // Find the center of the console vertically

    int width = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left; // Determine the width of the console
    int height = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top; // Determine the height of the console

    // Loop to draw a pattern in the console
    for (int size = 1; size <= width && size <= height; size += 2) {
        int x = centerX - size / 2; // Determine the starting X coordinate for the pattern
        int y = centerY - size / 2; // Determine the starting Y coordinate for the pattern

        // Draw the top line of the pattern
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Paint(hout, y, x + i);
        }

        // Draw the right line of the pattern
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            Paint(hout, y + i, x + size - 1);
        }

        // Draw the bottom line of the pattern
        for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            Paint(hout, y + size - 1, x + i);
        }

        // Draw the left line of the pattern
        for (int i = size - 2; i > 0; i--) {
            Paint(hout, y + i, x);
        }
    }

    getchar(); // Wait for user input before closing the program
    return 0; // End the program
}
```

The program is not executed for the entire size of the console, and not exactly according to the scheme.

Comment: Does it work on paper? So you start in the exact middle of the screen, then draw a horizontal line of size 1? That does not seem like the thing you were supposed to do according to your diagram. Start over and build the program piece by piece, verifying each piece as you go.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, when you loop to draw a pattern in the console, you should draw the right first. And draw the top line at the end.

```
    // Draw the right line of the pattern
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        Paint(hout, y  + i, x+ size - 1);
    }

   
    // Draw the bottom line of the pattern
    for (int i = size - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        Paint(hout, y  + size - 1, x + i);
    }

    // Draw the left line of the pattern
    for (int i = size - 2; i > 0; i--) {
        Paint(hout, y  + i, x );
    }

    // Draw the top line of the pattern
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Paint(hout, y, x  + i);
    }
```

Comment: thanks it helped me, but i still have two problems : 1)The  drawing performed by the program does not end in the upper left corner; 2)Еhe drawing is not performed on the entire console, but is drawn only in the center